# Cache in scheduled Laravel command

Tags: laravel, caching, server, command, schedule

Im having some trouble about running a command in the server.
I have a scheduled command to run hourly which i modified recently.

When i run it manually, it works correctly, but when the scheduler runs it, it works as the old version of the command core script.

I've tried to clear all kinds of cache (even supervisor cache, that im not sure it interferes)

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
    $schedule->command('ticket:completion')
            ->hourly();
}
```

Im not sure its a cache problem, but it seems so. Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: The Laravel scheduler doesn't cache your commands, the `php artisan schedule:run` gets executed once every minute, and each time it does, it evaluates the command code it finds at that moment. There's no caching (or serialization like for queued jobs) happening that would keep the old command code cached in some way. I have a feeling that the issue might be with something your command executes internally. Are you queuing some jobs as part of the command execution, that have changed as well?

Comment: It would help if you could post the command, that is if it doesn't contain any proprietary code that you're not allowed to share.

Answer (score 0):

I my case it was an another project with the same (but not modified) code base running the same server.

Comment: Look like a comment, more than a answer.